# Can Selenium be used to automate data retrieval from a 3rd party web portal?

Tags: selenium, automation

I need to automate a manual task to retrieve sales data from a web portal that is not setup for API access.

Can I use a test tool, such as Selenium, to do this task or is there a better solution out there.

I've never used Selenium but it looks easy enough to create record a macro for the button clicks to log in and initiate the download. I also need to trigger the download once a week, notify an email or slack channel if there is an error and then save the file with a specific name including the date.

My hope is that I can do all of this within an test automation tool but willing to explore other options.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be implemented. Once you succeed with fetching the data, change your webdriver run option to "**Headless**", so that Selenium will run at background and will not make the browser visible during runtime. An example for setting headless mode on **Firefox:**

```
FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
firefoxOptions.addArguments("--headless")
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options); // init driver in headless mode
```

After that you can use the fetched data in the rest of your program.